# How to make the element stop falling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below this text is my code - I am trying to create the chrome dino game, and so far everything is going well, but I have one problem - after the red block jumps, the dino doesn't stop falling down - while it should. I don't understand where my problem is, as I wrote about the same code yesterday and everything worked just fine. The gravity function can be found in the JavaScript under `// Gravity`.

Notice how it's code is very similar to the jump function, but it doesn't work as good as the jump function. Any help would be appreciated!!!!!

```js
// HTML Elements + Other Variables

const floor1 = document.getElementById("floor1");
const floor2 = document.getElementById("floor2");
const floor3 = document.getElementById("floor3");
const floor4 = document.getElementById("floor4");
const floor5 = document.getElementById("floor5");
const floor6 = document.getElementById("floor6");
const floor7 = document.getElementById("floor7");

const dino = document.getElementById("dino");

const highBird = document.getElementById("highBird");
const lowBird = document.getElementById("lowBird");

const wideCactus = document.getElementById("wideCactus");
const thinCactus = document.getElementById("thinCactus");

let jump = 0;

// Floor Function

setTimeout(function () {
    floor1.classList.add("floor1Animation");
}, 0);

setTimeout(function () {
    floor2.classList.add("floor2Animation");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    floor3.classList.add("floor3Animation");
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
    floor4.classList.add("floor4Animation");
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    floor5.classList.add("floor5Animation");
}, 4000);

setTimeout(function () {
    floor6.classList.add("floor6Animation");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function () {
    floor7.classList.add("floor7Animation");
}, 6000);

// Jump

document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    let key = event.key;
    if (key == "ArrowUp") {
        let jumpCount = 0;
        if (dino.offsetTop == 95) {
            let jumpInterval = setInterval(function () {
                dino.style.top = (dino.offsetTop - 5) + "px";
                jumpCount += 1;
                jump = true;
                if (jumpCount == 20) {
                    clearInterval(jumpInterval);
                    jump = false;
                    jumpCount = 0;
                }
            }, 10);
        }
    }
}

// Gravity

setInterval(function () {
    if (jump == false) {
        let jumpGravity = setInterval(function () {
            dino.style.top = (dino.offsetTop + 5) + "px";
        }, 10);
        if (dino.offsetTop == 95) {
            clearInterval(jumpGravity);
        }
    }
}, 10);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#gameBoard {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}

#dino {
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 10px;
    top: 95px;
    position: absolute;
}

.floorBackground {
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.floor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

#floor1 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.floor1Animation {
    animation: floorAnimation 6s infinite linear;
}

#floor2 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.floor2Animation {
    animation: floorAnimation 6s infinite linear;
}

#floor3 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: green;
}

.floor3Animation {
    animation: floorAnimation 6s infinite linear;
}

#floor4 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: purple;
}

.floor4Animation {
    animation: floorAnimation 6s infinite linear;
}

#floor5 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: brown;
}

.floor5Animation {
    animation: floorAnimation 6s infinite linear;
}

#floor6 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.floor6Animation {
    animation: floorAnimation 6s infinite linear;
}

#floor7 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.floor7Animation {
    animation: floorAnimation 6s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes floorAnimation {
    from {
        right: -200px;
    }
    to {
        right: 1000px;
    }
}

@keyframes jumping {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>
            Dino Game
        </title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "DinoCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "gameBoard">
            <div id = "floor1" class = "floor">
                <img src = "Pictures/dinoBackground.PNG" class = "floorBackground">
            </div>
            <div id = "floor2" class = "floor">
                <img src = "Pictures/dinoBackground.PNG" class = "floorBackground">
            </div>
            <div id = "floor3" class = "floor">
                <img src = "Pictures/dinoBackground.PNG" class = "floorBackground">
            </div>
            <div id = "floor4" class = "floor">
                <img src = "Pictures/dinoBackground.PNG" class = "floorBackground">
            </div>
            <div id = "floor5" class = "floor">
                <img src = "Pictures/dinoBackground.PNG" class = "floorBackground">
            </div>
            <div id = "floor6" class = "floor">
                <img src = "Pictures/dinoBackground.PNG" class = "floorBackground">
            </div>
            <div id = "floor7" class = "floor">
                <img src = "Pictures/dinoBackground.PNG" class = "floorBackground">
            </div>

            <div id = "dino"></div>
            <div id = "highBird"></div>
            <div id = "lowBird"></div>
            <div id = "wideCactus"></div>
            <div id = "thinCactus"></div>
        </div>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "DinoJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, im sorry. Most of the CSS and HTML is irrelevant but i added it to make game function as normal. I know the problem is with the gravity, just not what it is.

Comment: `dino.style.top = (dino.offsetTop + 5) + "px";`  I think you need to wrap this in a condition, like `if dino.offsetTop < 95`

Answer (score 0):

You should try simplifying your code, it may make the issue easier to find or it may even remove it entirely.

I'd suggest using a velocity system, where every frame you adjust the dino's offsetTop by the dino's current velocity, and then subtract the gravity amount from the dino's current velocity.

This causes the velocity to decrease at a constant rate, but the dino's offsetTop position to decrease at an exponential pace, mimicking real gravity.

Then, to make collision work, just test if the dino is at or above the correct "offsetTop" value before subtracting the gravity. If you find that the dino is below the ground, just set the offsetTop to the ground level and clear the velocity.

I'd also suggest moving your game over to the [HTML5 Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial), since then you just have to deal with properties of objects rather than DOM element style attributes.

Velocity example with canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var VelocityX = 0;
var VelocityY = 0;
const gravity = 0.75;

// width and height of the square
var width = 10;
var height = 10;

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    x += VelocityX;
        
    if( x > 500) {
        x = 0;
    }
    
    if ( y >= 450 ) {
        y = 450
      VelocityY = 0
        } else {
          y += VelocityY;
        VelocityY += gravity; // Higher values = lower position on canvas
    }
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

setInterval(animate, 1000 / 60); // 60 FPS
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvkaxmzh/4/)